# kind of a loop having a class passing itself to another one

Tags: php, reference

I'm building a music playlists plugin in PHP, and in an attempt to make my (big) code clear, I splitted each "pack" of functions inside classes, depending of what those functions are used for (eg. a class for the "cache" functions).

My main "playlist" object is passed inside each of those subclasses, because I NEED to access it all the time.
I did try to avoid passing the whole object, but I'm always stuck somewhere with that.  So having my main object passed in subclasses is very convenient for me.

Here's my problem : the code works well, the page prints in the browser, but... the browser loading wheel keep spinning, as if the page had not finished loading.

I guess the thing is that there is a problem self-referencing the same object everywhere (and nesting it), but I don't really understand *why* and foremost, how I could avoid that.
I got some hope when I saw the &$var thing ([Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)), which seems to make a "link" and not a copy of a variable, but it hasn't resolved my problem, the wheel keeps spinning.

I apologize if my question is not totally clear.  I have myself problems to understand the whole thing, and as english is not my first language, it's even more difficult to explain to you.

My code is quite big so i'll try to make an illustration of my problem here.

```
class Playlist{
    var $cache;
    function __construct(){
        $this->cache = new PlaylistCache($this); //I guess this may produce problems
        $this->admin = new PlaylistAdmin($this); //I guess this may produce problems
    }
}

class PlaylistCache{
    var $playlist;
    function __construct($playlist){
        $this->playlist = $playlist;
    }
}

class PlaylistAdmin{
    var $playlist;
    function __construct($playlist){
        $this->playlist = $playlist;
    }
}

$playlist = new Playlist();
```

Do you think those references are causing my problem ?
Thanks !

Comment: Above is valid php. It is perfectly fine to have object instances within your class definitions. Roughly what is the $playlist your'e passing in the contstructor? Is it just a very large array?

Comment: if the page loads, it is likely the php code has finished (if not you know what you have been doing). You need to debug the process a but more to find the issue but i would be checking onload evts first.

Comment: @eggmatters : the $playlist passed to the constructors of the "subclasses" is the Playlist class itself (see the constructor of the Playlist class) :)

Comment: @David : onload events ? Then javascript ? It still does happens when javascript is disabled in my browser.
BUT : when I did disable the Query Monitor plugin (a dev plugin for WP), it doesn't happen anymore !! YEAH !  I'm still afraid a problem in my code make it bug.

Comment: well at least you know what it is. No your code looks ok, i though there might have been ajax onload that was not completing, but of course just guessing blind here.

Comment: I was asking more about the data. Anyways, it just occurred to me to look for other resources that might be causing the wheel spinner. Open up firebug/developer tools and look at all the request events. Oftentimes, there's a js CDN call taking forever (google-web-fonts is a good example)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without looking at how you're using the code you posted, but it looks like you have your class inheritance backwards. Instead of your Playlist class having the other two classes in it, you should have the other two inherit the methods from your playlist class.

[PHP Object Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

This way, your Playlist class will be the Base class that has all the common methods the other two classes may need.

```
class PlaylistCache extends Playlist
{
    // this class has all public methods from Playlist
}

class PlaylistAdmin extends Playlist
{
    // this class has all public methods from Playlist
}
```

The link above should have more on this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about this.  But it also means I can't call the subclasses from within the main one ? (in my first example, I can call the cache class with $this->cache... from within the Playlist class), which I can't anymore ?

Comment: There's two ways of going about it, one is Inheritance (what i posted), the other is [Dependency Injection](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146) (Similar to what you're already doing).  If using inheritance, you would use the Subclasses first, then access the inherited methods there. $cache = new PlaylistCache(); this would let you do cache related things and still be able to call methods in the main Playlist class from the $cache instance.